# Get client public ip from request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ip, httprequest

I'm using node.js, hosting in my local dev machine, and testing in it.

The only thing I could get is `127.0.0.1`, which is my local host.

1) This is what I tried so far:

```
request.connection.remoteAdrress (127.0.0.1)
request.socket.remoteAddress (127.0.0.1)
request._remoteAddress (127.0.0.1)
request.ip (not found)
```

2) And I'm surprised `request.headers` is `null`, so I cannot access `request.headers[‘x-forward-for’]`

3) I even print out the JSONS `request.connection`, `request.socket`, `request`

The only thing I found which is an IP, is `127.0.0.1`

So how could I get client's public ip, without using 3rd party libraries?

Comment: What proxy are you using?

Comment: are you using socketio?

Comment: If you're testing from the local host, it uses the loopback interface to communicate, so you can't get the public IP.

Comment: @Barmar so there's no way to get it, if I hosting on my own machine?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique I saw it's installed in our code base, but didn't use it

Comment: Try connecting to your public address instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Luca I dont think we use proxy

Comment: https://gist.github.com/qiao/1626318

Comment: @EleazarEnrique we are using node express